# Dropbox api: Can someone provide a HTTP request example?

Tags: http-headers, dropbox-api

Could someone show me an example or a starting point on how Dropbox api http requests should look?

For example if I want to receive tokens how would the HTTP/1.1 request look like for this?
I'm planning on writing a program in C using sockets,

```
write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

What should buffer look like to receive security tokens from dropbox? I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

The official SDKs on the Dropbox developer site each include working examples that you can work from:
    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk